# Typescript index signature class extends class

Tags: typescript, types, interface, extends

I try build block editor with Typescript. My problem is as follows...

I have this:

```
class A {...}

class B extends A {...}
class C extends A {...}
class D {...}

interface AConstructable {
  new (): A;
}
interface AElements {
  [name: string]: AConstructable
}
enter code here
const test: AElements = {
  blockB: B // ??? this takes B, but have type A :/ 
}
```

I need this:

```
const test: AElements = {
  blockB: B // ok!
  blockC: C // error
}

const x1 = new test['blockB'](...) // return B class instance
```

I tried different ways the above is closest but I don't know how to bite it. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In typescript anything which extends a type is assignable to that type.  You require that the properties of `AElements` are each a constructor that returns an `A`.  It is fine to return a `B` or a `C` because all `B`s and `C`s are also `A`s.

The only reason that you have an error on `blockC` is because of a missing comma.  This code is actually fine:

```
const test: AElements = {
  blockB: B,
  blockC: C
}
```

But that code will still show the value constructed by `new test.blockB()` as `A` because we haven't preserved any individual information about the properties.

In order to keep the types of the individual property values while also enforcing that they extend `A`, you can create `test` through an identity function.  Using a function allows allows to infer the exact types of the `blockB` and `blockC` and keep them, while also requiring that the object fits the index signature.

```
const checkObject = <T extends {}>(obj: T & AElements): T & AElements => obj;

const test = checkObject({
  blockB: B,
  blockC: C
});

const x1 = new test['blockB']() // return B class instance
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/BmxG8N)

Comment: Thx. It's works for me. I shoud spend a lot of time with TS types :D